# Редактирование текста pastebin через python

Tags: python

Как можно редактировать текст в pastebin через python? У меня есть программа для которой нужно сделать ключи активации. Если ключ активирован, его нужно удалить с pastebin и записать серийный номер диска того кто активировал в другой файл в pastebin, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

воспользуйся своим апи у меня есть базовый пример:

```
url = f"https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"
params = {
    "api_dev_key": api_key,
    "api_user_key": "",
    "api_option": "list",
}
```